# How to check if each word in an array contains a substring and reject those in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
a = ["SUPER", "SOME_VALID", "ROME_INVALID", "SUPER_GOOD"]
a = a.reject { |x| x.in? ["GOOD", "VALID"]}
#=> ["SUPER", "SOME_VALID", "ROME_INVALID", "SUPER_GOOD"]
```

I don't want words that contain substring VALID or GOOD.

Output should be `["SUPER"]` only.

Comment: Is "ROME_INVALID" to be included? What about "valid"? What does "SUPER only" mean? Please edit to show your desired return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say this:

```rb
a = a.reject { |x| x.include?("GOOD") || x.include?("VALID")}
```

Comment: You can use `a.reject! { ... }` (with a `!`) instead of re-assigning the result to `a`.

Comment: ...or `x.match?(/GOOD|VALID/)`. I was reminded by @3limin4t0r's comment on Stefan's answer that perhaps better would be `bad_strings = ["GOOD", "VALID"]; r = Regexp.union(bad_strings) #=> /GOOD|VALID/; a.reject { |x| x.match?(r) } #=> ["SUPER"]`. That way only the array `bad_strings` need be changed if the collection of bad strings changes in future (the possible future to always be kept in mind).

Comment: @CarySwoveland, regex - grhh ;)

Comment: @Fabio, as I recall, "grhh" in Italian means "aaah" in English.

Answer (score 4):

[`grep_v`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v) would work:

```
a = ["SUPER", "SOME_VALID", "ROME_INVALID", "SUPER_GOOD"]
a = a.grep_v(/GOOD|VALID/)
#=> ["SUPER"]
```

Comment: If you need a more dynamic approach: `Regexp.union(%w[GOOD VALID])` would generate the regex dynamically.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't know what version of Ruby you are running but it has a different result when I run it: `a = %w[b b c]; a - a.grep(/c/) #=> ["b", "b"]` (ruby 2.6.5p114). There is however no reason to do additional computation subtracting arrays when you can use `grep_v` and have the correct result with one iteration.

Comment: @CarySwoveland although `['a', 'a', 'c', 'c'] - ['c']` will remove both `'c'`'s, it will also keep both `'a'`'s.

Comment: I was, what, sleepy? (Was composing on a phone.) Allowing me to blame it on the version of Ruby I was using brought a smile to my face.

Answer (score 3):

What `in?` does is to check if the receiver is present in the array passed as argument, meaning:

```
1.in?([1, 2]) # true
3.in?([1, 2]) # false
```

That's to say, it checks for the "whole" object, rather than a part of it.

If you want to reject the elements in your array that match with `VALID` and/or `GOOD`, you can use `=~`:

```
["SUPER", "SOME_VALID", "ROME_INVALID", "SUPER_GOOD"].reject { |word| word =~ /VALID|GOOD/ } # ["SUPER"]
```

Notice, this is also going to reject words like "VALIDITY", "GOODNESS", etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`include?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
a.reject { |x| ["GOOD", "VALID"].any?{ |word| x.include?(word) } }
#=> ["SUPER"]
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Updated my question for much more clarity